# A better algorithm for a "Tournament"

Tags: c, performance, algorithm

I have a question. I have been preparing for ZCO since a few days and I ran across a pretty simple problem which I've been unable to solve within the time limit of 3secs. Here goes the problem:

> N teams participate in a league cricket tournament on Mars, where each
>   pair of distinct teams plays each other exactly once. Thus, there are
>   a total of (N × (N­1))/2 matches. An expert has assigned a strength to
>   each team, a positive integer. Strangely, the Martian crowds love
>   one­sided matches and the advertising revenue earned from a match is
>   the absolute value of the difference between the strengths of the two
>   matches. Given the strengths of the N teams, find the total
>   advertising revenue earned from all the matches.
>
> For example, suppose N is 4 and the team strengths for teams 1, 2, 3,
>   and 4 are 3, 10, 3, and 5 respectively. Then the advertising revenues
>   from the 6 matches are as follows:
>
> 7, 0, 2, 7, 5, 2
>
> Thus the total advertising revenue is 23.
>
> Sample input 4 3 10 3 5 Sample output 23 Test data In all subtasks,
>   the strength of each team is an integer between 1 and 1,000 inclusive.
>
> Subtask 1 (30 marks) : 2 ≤ N ≤ 1,000.
>   Subtask 2 (70 marks) : 2 ≤ N ≤ 200,000.
>
> Limits
>
> Time limit : 3s
>
> Memory limit: 64 MB

SO, I've opted for a simple algorithm that scans and finds the ad revenue for every team as corresponding to all other teams before it. This amounts to a **O(n^2)** which fails to pass subtask 2. I don't think that it's possible to improve over this, could anyone help me ?

P.S. Though it doesn't help, but here's my current C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long int n, i, j;
    scanf("%lld", &n);
    long long int A[n], strength = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &A[i]);
        for(j = i;j >= 0;j--)
        {
            strength += A[i] > A[j] ? A[i] - A[j] : A[j] - A[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%lld\n", strength);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have 10 teams, call them A, B, C, ..., J from strongest to weakest. Let's look at the match between A and J. It has an interesting property: the revenue from that match is the same as the sum of revenues from two other matches, AB and BJ. Oh, and also AC and CJ. And... Wow, by multiplying AJ by 9 we have sum of revenues of all the matches with either A or J! Now we have just 8 teams left. Let's look at the match B vs I. It has an interesting property... Ain't math wonderful?

Comment: Why making it community wiki ? It's well earned rep :)

Comment: Wow. I'm blown away by your observation. But can your prove this mathematically ? I mean, it's an abnormal observation.

Comment: Where I come from, this observation counts as a proof, as mathematical as you can get. You would want to replace 10 with `N` for maximum rigour. Now if you are a Bourbaki member or something, you may want still *a bit* more rigour, but then if you are a Bourbaki member you don't normally seek advice on SO.